# Broken pipe error - while existing client terminate and new client join to ther server

Tags: java, sockets

I am getting the broken pipe error while the client stopping the build process and new client connect with server and sending message to the server.

Here my Server code:

```
public class Server {

     ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> ListOfclientOutputStreams;

     public Server() {

        ListOfclientOutputStreams = new ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream>();  
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7503);
            while(true) {               
                Socket serverCommunicationSocket;
                serverCommunicationSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                ObjectOutputStream eachClientobjectOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serverCommunicationSocket.getOutputStream());                                             
                ListOfclientOutputStreams.add(eachClientobjectOutStream);  
                Thread threadForSpecificClient = new Thread(new SpecificClient(serverCommunicationSocket));
                threadForSpecificClient.start();
                System.out.println("Got a connection");
            }
        }catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}

private class SpecificClient implements Runnable {

        private ObjectInputStream eachClientObjectInputStream;  
        private Socket sock;

        public SpecificClient(Socket specificSocket) {

            try {
                sock = specificSocket;
                eachClientObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            }catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {

            Message msgObject;
            try {
                while((msgObject = (Message) eachClientObjectInputStream.readObject()) !=null) {
                    System.out.println("Client thread on the server read" + msgObject);
                    broadCast(msgObject);
                }
            }catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
                System.out.println("Unable to read the message object in server");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void broadCast(Message msgObject) {

            Iterator<ObjectOutputStream> iter = ListOfclientOutputStreams.iterator();
            try {
                while(iter.hasNext()) {
                    ObjectOutputStream out = iter.next();
                    out.writeObject(msgObject);                   
                    out.flush();    
                }
            }catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to add the Message object to the outputstream in the server");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Server server1 = new Server();
}   
}
```

This is my client coding:

```
public class Client {
    private ObjectOutputStream clientOutStream;
    private ObjectInputStream clientInStream;
    private Socket clientSocket;

    public Client() throws InterruptedException {
        establishConnection();
        createStreams();
        Thread threadToRead = new Thread(new Incoming()); 
        threadToRead.start();
    }

    public void establishConnection() {

    try {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(Session.port);
        clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
        System.out.println("Network connection Established");
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void createStreams() {

    try {
        clientInStream = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        clientOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Connection streams established");
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class Incoming implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        String personIn;
        Message msgObject = new Message();
        try 
        {
            personIn=personLoggedIn.getText().toString();

            while((msgObject= (Message) clientInStream.readObject()) !=null)
            {
                    //updateWhoIsOnline();
                System.out.println("Client is Reading the object from the server");
                String postedTo = msgObject.getPostedTo().replace(",", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                    System.out.println("Posted To : "+postedTo);
                    String[] result = postedTo.split(" ");
                    int len = result.length;
                    System.out.println("Length : "+len);
                    System.out.println("First string : "+result[0].toString());
                    //System.out.println("Second string : "+result[1].toString());
                    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
                        if(result[i].toString().equals("All") || result[i].toString().equals(personIn) || msgObject.getPostedBy().equals(personIn)) {
                            chatDetailsViewArea.append(msgObject.getPostedBy() + " ->" +  result[i].toString() + ":" + msgObject.getContent() + "\n");
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in figuring out who to post the message to");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you need help with?  What's your question?

Comment: You're making at least three major mistakes. (1) You're creating object streams in the accept thread. They should be created in the `run()` method of the handler thread. Otherwise you can block the accept loop. (2) You're testing `readObject()` for returning `null.` It doens't return `null` unless you wrote `null,` and that isn't necessarily a signal to stop reading objects. You should be catching `EOFException` instead to detect end of stream. (3) You're creating the `ObjectInputStream` before the `ObjectOutputStream.` That can cause a deadlock. The `ObjectOutputStream` must be created first.